# How to test a function that returns functions?

Tags: javascript, function, unit-testing, purely-functional, pure-function

Here I have a function `generateBlocks` that takes in an array `blocks` and a function `onBlockClick`. It returns an array of object where each object has two properties `label` and `onClick`.

```
function generateBlocks(blocks, onBlockClick){
   return blocks.map(block => (
     {
        label: block.label,
        onClick: ()=>onBlockClick(block.name)
     }
 ))
}
```

I'm unable test it's return value.
Here's the test case:

```
const blocks = [{label: "A", name: "a"}, {label: "B", name: "b"}];
const onBlockClick = someFunction(){};

expect(generateBlocks(blocks, onBlockClick)).to.deep.equal(expected)
```

I cannot create `expected` as `[[{label: "A", onClick: ()=>onBlockClick("A")},...]` because function reference will be different.

So how do I refactor generateBlocks function to make it testable?

Comment: The first step you've taken is to ask **"How do I test it?"**. The next thing you should ask yourself is **"What do I want to test here?"**. It's hard to refactor existing code to make it testable if you don't actually know what you want to test.

Comment: Well, don't use `deep.equal`? Just assert that every object has a `.label` and that its `.onclick()` returns the name when you pass in the identity function for `onBlockClick`.

Comment: @Brandon Please see the test case which **clearly explains** what I want to test which is **the return value**.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't get you, what do you mean returns the name? onBlockClick does not return anything.

Comment: @ArjunU.: But if it did, `onClick` would as well, and you could easily test that return value. Or you use a library like sinon to spy on the invocations.

Comment: @Bergi I will test the onClick when I test the View component but in this case consider it's just another function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .toString() method on the function ref and compare to expected string result.

Comment: I first thought so, but this will only  return the function code, which might change. You want to test for results, hence you need to call the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837070/5037146

Comment: Function that is returned might not be callable in all contexts... The only right answer to many of these question is "it depends". Sometimes the simplest solution that could take you 80% there is the best thing to do.