# Jest: How to test function that returns a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have several functions I would like to test with Jest. All functions are functions that return functions.

A simple example:

```
export function csl(foo) {
  return function(bar) {
      return(bar)
     };
}
```

now I want to test if the input = the return is. I try it with:

```
  expect(() => csl("foo")).toBe("foo") // = received: [Function anonymous]

  expect(csl("foo")).toBe("foo") // = received: undefined
```

How I can test these functions?

Comment: @CodyＧ [oh gods, no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805478/how-to-test-two-returned-functions-with-different-argument-value-in-javascript/56806249#56806249)

Comment: @VLAZ Agreed, I don't know what Ckappo wants by looking at the function and not the result from the function generated... but now I am realizing they might not know how to call a function.

Comment: @CodyＧ seems like a fairly standard test, with the only "twist" being that it's testing a function that returns a function. So it's just missing a second execution for the inner function. I went to check the Jest docs if there is any better way to do it and then to see if there is a CDN copy to demonstrate how to do it but **Ji aSH** answered in the mean time with basically what I wanted to say. Couldn't find a CDN copy to demonstrate better.

Answer (score 9):

You need to call the returned function

```
expect(csl("foo")("bar")).toBe("bar")
                 ^^^^^^^
```